# some sun time errors in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, function-call, function-declaration, function-prototypes

full code is this:
Insertion  in linked  list
Please  make it like it run smoothly then After  i will debug on basis of my algorithms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define  null 0
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct  node *next;
};
int insertion(struct node**,struct node**,int,int);

int main()
{
  struct  node *head=null,*tail=null,*next=null;
  int pos,result,input;
  head->next=null;
  int choice;
  while(1)
  {
   printf ("choices:\n");
   printf ("1:insertion\n");
   printf ("2:deletion");
   printf ("0:exit\n");
   scanf("%d",&choice);
   switch(choice)
   {
     case 1:
        
        printf("Enter position for insertion:");
        scanf("%d",&pos );
        printf("Enter element to insert:");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        printf("linked  list before insertion:");
        while(head->next!=null)
       {
        printf ("%d->",head->data);
        head=head->next;
       }
       result=insertion(&head,&tail,pos,input);
       if(result==-1)
       printf ("Insertion failed!!");
       else
      {
        printf ("Insertion success\n");
        printf ("linked list after insertion:");
        while(head->next!=null)
        {
         printf ("%d->",head->data);
         head=head->next;
        }
      }
       break;
  // case 2:
      
   case 0:
       exit(0);
   default:
       printf ("Wrong choice\n");
   }
   return 0;
 }
}
int  insertion(struct node** head,struct node** tail,int pos,int input)
```

its  showing  some Run error.

i have deleted function definition  but still i think errors  is in the given piece  of code only.

Comment: Two different functions with same name is not legal in C – unless you make at least one of them static and the other one resides in another compilation unit.

Comment: The error messages tell you what the problem is.  At line 3, you have `struct node *head, struct node *tail` in the prototype/declaration.  At line 58, you have `struct node **head, struct node **tail` in the function definition.  The types are different.  Choose one and fix the other.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to correct the formatting! Until then, my crystal ball was saying there's `struct nodehead` and `struct nodetail` definitions somewhere.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of having to pass `head` and `tail` to `insertion` (and other linked list functions), create a `struct linked_list { struct node *head, *tail; }` to keep that information and pass pointers to an instance of that to the functions instead. `insert_first(struct linked_list *ll, struct node *node_to_insert);` and `insert_last(struct linked_list *ll, struct node *node_to_insert);` etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please add relevant snippets of the source code that produces this error to your question?